# table header is stacking on top of each other for Fixed property

Tags: javascript, html, css

All the header elements of my table are stacked on top of one another when the `<table>`'s position is fixed.

How can I fix this issue so that all the table header elements will be aligned properly with the column property?

```
Note. I do not want to use sticky and only looking of a solution with `Fixed`
```

```css
table {
  /* border: 5px solid red; */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 100%;
}

thead {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

tbody {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  position: fixed;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account No.</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Transaction Details</th>
      <th>Value date</th>
      <th>details</th>
      <th>Deposit AMT</th>
      <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>ALJDFLDOI 4584</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>This is test data !This is test data !This is test data !</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>ALJDFLDOI 4584</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>This is test data !This is test data !This is test data !</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>ALJDFLDOI 4584</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>This is test data !This is test data !This is test data !</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>ALJDFLDOI 4584</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>This is test data !This is test data !This is test data !</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I have changed display of table to `block` which will help the table to be aligned horizontally center.
2. I have given `position: sticky; top: 0` to thead `tr` which will make it stick to top when scrolled.
3. I have given `min-width: 100px;` to th, td which will set the minimum width of each cell and will make sure that the width of the cells of the header matches the width of the cells of the body.

Last, I have removed `flex-flow: column;, display: table; and table-layout: fixed;` as they are not required.
I have set `overflow-y: auto; and overflow-x: hidden;` on tbody element to make the body scrollable if the content is overflowing.

```css
table {
    /* border: 5px solid red; */
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

thead tr {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

tbody {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

th, td {
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account No.</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Transaction Details</th>
      <th>Value date</th>
      <th>details</th>
      <th>Deposit AMT</th>
      <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>ALJDFLDOI 4584</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>This is test data !This is test data !This is test data !</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>ALJDFLDOI 4584</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>This is test data !This is test data !This is test data !</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>ALJDFLDOI 4584</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>This is test data !This is test data !This is test data !</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>ALJDFLDOI 4584</td>
      <td>10-10-2023</td>
      <td>This is test data !This is test data !This is test data !</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>
```

Comment: Additionally, might want a background: `thead tr { background: #aaa; }`

Comment: @tivi I am searching a solution with display: Fixed. Unfortunately In my app sticky is not working at all